# How to make my entire tab clicakble in WPF

Tags: wpf, events, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl Template and style, but i am having some issues with the clickable are in the tabs.

You will notice that my tab (Border below) has a width and height specified, but unfortunately, the entire border is not clickable, it is only the text inside it, so if i have one letter in the tab, you have to point your mouse exactly on the letter to select the tab.

How can i make it that if you click anywhere on inside the border it selects the tab?

Here is my ControlTemplate:

```
<Style x:Key="MainTabItem" TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="#EAF1F7" CornerRadius="3,3,0,0" Height="60" Width="70" Margin="-2,0,2,0">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#EDF1FA" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#EAF1F7" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="MainTabControl" TargetType="TabControl">

    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#CFE2F0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EAF1F7"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#EAF1F7"/>
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect Direction="150" BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="5" Opacity=".3"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#EAF1F7" />
                <GradientStop Offset=".2" Color="#EAF1F7" />
                <GradientStop Offset=".6" Color="#C7D7E4" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#EAF1F7" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the border add `Background="Transparent"`.

The reason is that default value for background is `null`, and pixels with 'null' value are not hit test visible. Transparent pixels are hit test visible (and that's the main reason why 'null' and 'Transparent' exist together).